# get actions for jungle testnet

Tags: cleos

I was trying to retrieve list of actions for an account I created in jungle testnet.

```
cleos --url http://dev.cryptolions.io:38888 get actions <account_name>
```

using this code.

However, it returns nothing. I added `history_api_plugin` when running nodeos. 
How can I retrieve the list?

Comment: Your nodeos does do anything incase of jungle test net. Jungle test net has it's own node running. What error did you get ..?

Comment: do jungle testnet work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the actions of your contract including table:

```
cleos --url http://dev.cryptolions.io:38888 get abi <your_account>
```

or

```
cleos --url https://junglehistory.cryptolions.io:443 get abi <account_name>
```

account_name is the account with which you set your contract.

if you want **action performed** by a account on jungle test net you can get like this:

```
cleos --url https://junglehistory.cryptolions.io:443 get actions <your_account> -1 -100 -j
```

where -100  is the last 100 transactions. You may also get last 2 , or last 3 as you want.

Comment: This is not an answer related to this because the question is about to actions that performed by account and the answer given by you is about actions which is used in contract here both are different.

Comment: @Mr.Y thanks for pointing the right direction, language of question is little bit confusing about what you said. So I edited the answer and also keep the earlier answer,  as jinjineos does'nt share his/her views.